# how to use a different theme only for cart page and one page chackout page in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, customize

How can we use  different theme only for cart page and one page chackout page in Magento ?

I am talking about following pages:
- *domain.com/checkout/cart/*
- *domain.com/checkout/onepage/*.

Is it possible to do do with `Admin > CMS > Pages` ? Can some one please explain how to do this?

Comment: its possible, not via cms -> pages, you need to customise and override the default cart and checkout template and implant your theme

Comment: What you mean by different theme in your context? It means you want to completely change the look and feel of those pages or you have a different skin which you would like to use in those pages ?